# Replacing geom_rug with geom_boxplot for huge data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to visualize a relationship between continuous `x` and binary `y` ([inspiration](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/45463/69374))

```
set.seed(1032490)
NN = 2e5
DF = data.frame(x = rlnorm(NN))
DF$y = as.numeric(DF$x - mean(DF$x) + rnorm(NN) > 0)
ggplot(DF, aes(x, y)) + 
  stat_smooth(method = 'gam') + 
  geom_rug(sides = 'b')
```

[image: A plot as described. There is no title; the axes are labeled "x" and "y". The main plotting area shows a simple blue line at a 45 degree angle upwards. Underneath this, at the very bottom on the x axis, is a "rug" plot of small vertical lines showing the distribution of x points; it is clustered to the left (there is no visible space between points below x=30) and sparser on the right (the highest point, x=80, is about 20 higher than the next lowest point)]

Of course with this many points, a rug is not very useful, and it also slows down plotting considerably.

Faster and more interpretable would be to replace `geom_rug` with a boxplot (or other distribution-summarizing plot).

Is there any out-of-the-box way to do so? I played around with `geom_boxplot` and checked the documentation to no avail.

Comment: See [`ggExtra::ggMarginal` - Add marginal histograms/boxplots/density plots](https://github.com/daattali/ggExtra)

Comment: @Henrik those look quite nice indeed

Comment: Great! When I struggle with non-vanilla ggplot stuff, I often find it useful to browse through [these ggplot extensions](http://www.ggplot2-exts.org/gallery/). Quite often the wheel is invented already.

Comment: @Henrik very helpful. I wasn't sure if I'd just missed something in base `ggplot` since I'm quite a beginner and `geom_rug` is built in.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `geom_boxploth` from package `ggstance`, although I am not sure this is your desired output?

```
library(ggstance)

ggplot(DF, aes(x, y)) + 
  stat_smooth(method = 'gam') + 
  geom_boxploth(aes(y = -1, x = x))
```

[image]

Comment: looks pretty good! of course `x` should be on the log scale but that's a separate issue